# How do I trigger the mobile.loading method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to do something that appears to be fairly simple.  Basically I have an Ajax event listener that checks for the Ajax start event and Ajax end event, and when a start or end even is detected, it should run `$.mobile.loading('show')` and when the Ajax event ends it should run `$.mobile.loading('hide')`.  However, the loading icon and text does not show.

Thinking there was something wrong with my Ajax event start and event end listeners were not picking up the Ajax start and end events correctly I, replaced the `$.mobile.loading('show')` with a standard alert, which worked correctly. Here is my code:

```js
$("#page1").ajaxStart(function() { $.mobile.loading('show'); });
```

and

```js
$("#page1").ajaxEnd(function() { $.mobile.loading('hide'); });
```

I know I am doing something wrong, but I do not know what.  Any idea?

Oh and in the case it matters, this JQM application is running under cordova (1.7.0) and jquery 1.8.1 and jquery mobile 1.1.1

The libraries are loaded in that order and the event listeners are loaded after the device ready event.

so:

```js
function onBodyLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }

function onDeviceReady() {
    / load the ajax start and end listeners code displayed above /
}
```

**EDIT:**  Here is what my document head looks like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onBodyLoad()
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady()
{
    $("#page1").ajaxStart(function() {
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    });

    $("#page1").ajaxStop(function() {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    });
}
```

Page 1 has some form fields that are enhanced by JQM, and when the user clicks the submit button, it runs a function that checks if the user is connected to the network, and if they are, submits that data via Ajax.  The `$.mobile.loading` method should run while the Ajax is doing its thing, but it doesn't.

Comment: Which version of jQM are you running? $.mobile.loading() was only introduced in version 1.2.

Comment: Great catch.  I am using jQM 1.1.1.  I didn't know I was looking at the docs for jQM 1.2.  So I guess I should use `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure jquerymobile is initialized by the time you are calling your ajax? Here is what you can try and worked for me. (You can further cleanup the code by namespacing variables but this should give an idea)

```
var deviceready = false, pageinitialized = false;
function onBodyLoad() { 
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
   $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
     pageinitialized =true;
     myloading();
   });
}

function onDeviceReady() {
 / load the ajax start and end listeners code displayed above /
  myloading();
}

var myLoading = function(){
 if ( !deviceready || !pageinitialized ) {
  return
 }
 //Your ajax call here

}
```

Comment: Thanks kiran.  I am lost as it doesn't seem pageinit is firing regardless of where in the document head I place it.  I am sure it has to do with how or the order in which I am loading things.  Any suggestions?

Comment: May be silly, but is your `onBodyLoad` connected to `body onload='OnBodyLoad()'` ?

Comment: Yes, the body tag should load OnBodyLoad, when it loads.  LOL if that makes any sense.